# what is the difference between spark javardd methods collect() & collectAsync()?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am exploring the spark 2.0 java api and have a doubt regarding `collect()` & `collectAsync()` available for javardd.

Comment: `collect()` returns List of elements in RDD straightaway. `collectAsync()` gives future object from that element can be retrived.

Comment: Hi @JaydeepRameshDeshmukh, if any answer of the below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Collect action is basically used to view the content of RDD, basically it is synchronous while collectAsync() is asynchronous meaning it Returns a future for retrieving all elements of this RDD. it allows to run other RDD to run in parallel. for better optimization you can utilize fair scheduler for job scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

## collect():

It returns an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 1);
List<Integer> result = rdd.collect(); 
//elements in will be copied to driver in above step and control will 
//wait till the action completes
```

---

## collectAsync():

The **asynchronous version of `collect`**, which returns a **Future**(`java.util.concurrent.Future`) for retrieving an array containing all of the elements in this RDD.

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 1);
JavaFutureAction<List<Integer>> future = rdd.collectAsync(); 
// retuns only future object but not data (no latency here)

List<Integer> result = future.get(); 
//Now elements in will be copied to driver
```

> We see the diff in how we receive data only whether synchronous(**thread will wait till action completes in `collect()`**) or asynchronous(**thread will get Future object and pass on to next instruction**)