# Collect a Dataset in Spark Asynchronously

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

Like RDDs have `collectAsync()`, is there a way to collect a dataset asynchronously in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

yes collectAsync() is the way that collect a dataset asynchronously.

In RDD operation, collectAsync() has no latency on the other hand collect().

```
val value = rdd.collect() //RDD elements will be copied to spark driver 
val value = rdd.collectAsync() //no copy here  
value.get() //Now, RDD elements will be copied to spark driver
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I'm looking for a dataset function, not RDD.

Answer (score -2):

Someone has already given an answer here, Please check the link

[what is the difference between spark javardd methods collect() & collectAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333190/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-javardd-methods-collect-collectasync)

Comment: Did you open that link? what i said is check the link

Comment: I did. It states the difference between `collect` and `collectAsync`. You have enough reputation to comment. If you think this is a duplicate, you comment that on the question and flag it as such.